# How to open a file to standard output and append in C

Tags: c

Trying to open a file to standard output on append mode like this:

```
int f2;
f2 = open(STDOUT_FILENO,O_APPEND|O_CREAT);
```

but this code is not working (f2==-1 after opening). What is the problem? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to open standard output in that way?

Answer (score 1):

Given that `stdout` is already open with the flags you desire, you don't need to (and shouldn't) try actually opening it. Just [use `dup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) if you need a duplicate descriptor for stdout:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int f2 = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Note: Both handles share the file pointer, so you can't `lseek` them independently. Luckily, since this is `stdout` we're talking about, "seeking" is a meaningless concept anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This made a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

there is syntax error in the code
first you have to define the file pointer. and then define the read or write option
for example
FILE *in_file  = fopen("name_of_file", "r"); // read only
          FILE *out_file = fopen("name_of_file", "w"); // write only

Comment: This is about the OS provided system call `open`, not the `stdio.h` provided `fopen`. You're not addressing the question at all.